# Visual Studio - Find where unhandled exception occurs in user code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In a multi-threaded project, I have come across some unhandled exception:

```
0xC0000005: access violation at 0x00000000
```

and the arrow pointed to some line of `qstring.h`. I don't know which line of my code leads to this violation.

How can I find the location of the access violation in my code ?

[image]

Is this the `call stack` ?  I really can't understand this.

Comment: Most likely you are dereferencing a null pointer. Unfortunately, without seeing any code we really have no way to help you

Comment: I do know that. The project just has too much code and I don't know which part leads to the violation. I want to know where do I walk into `qstring.h`, or the call stack. @AndyProwl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Debug menu, Exceptions.

In this dialog, tick the exceptions you want to catch (edit: Access Violation will be in the Win32 section. You can browse the tree structure of exceptions or just click Find to search by name)

Now run your code under the debugger and vs will break whenever an exception is thrown.

Now open the call stack (Debug > Window > Call Stack) to see what functions are causing the problem. You can double click any line in the call stack to jump to the code and look at variable values from that method in the debugger. Search back up the stack until you find the last method in **your** code that the program was executing.

In many cases the problem will be blatantly obvious at this point (e.g. a variable that is null), but it may be state that is set up elsewhere that is passing through that method to cause the crash (e.g. a null in a struct that you are passing through to library calls), in which case you will have to look further afield to find out when and where that null value was set. This may be further up the call stack, or it may be state that was set up a long time before in a completely different method - but finding what your code was doing immediately before the crash will give you a lot of clues about where to look to find the source of the problem.

If you can identify the data value that is causing the access violation, then you may be able to add a conditional breakpoint (e.g. on that memory location changing) so that you can catch the point at which the value is set incorrectly. Another approach is to use accessor methods to set the value so you can breakpoint them and step through the code until you find the call that sets an incorrect value into it. Or you may just have to desk check the code for logic flaws.

Comment: This, except that "access violation" is listed under "Win32 Exceptions", not "C++ Exceptions".

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `Call Stack` window in Visual Studio.

While Visual Studio usually shows the call stack of the thread that raised an exception (and it's usually sufficient to track down the error), it might be useful to look through other threads (double-clicking them in `Threads` pane) to know what they were doing at that point of time.

Comment: Yes, this is the call stack. It shows function calls preceding the exception. Navigate through the call stack down and double-click lines to see where the functions were called from (I think there should be your code somewhere).

Comment: Thanks, some of the call stack is readable C++ code and others assembly. Accidentally the call stack in this post is pure assembly.

Comment: Make sure that it's a Debug configuration, and that debug information included into executable (this is set Linker settings).